# Validation using entity for a FormType inside a form

Tags: php, validation, symfony-forms, symfony

I have two entities: `Company` and `Location`. One company has one location (while one location may "have" multiple companies). Now when a user creates a company, I want him/her to able able, to create the location in the same form. So I use the following

```
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class, ['label' => 'company.name'])
        ->add('size', IntegerType::class, ['label' => 'company.size'])
        ->add( $builder->create('location', FormType::class, [
                'label' => 'company.location',
                'by_reference' => true,
                'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Location',
            ])
            ->add('street', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'location.street',
            ])
            ->add('number', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'location.number',
            ])
```

This works fine in creating the form. Now it comes to validation. I added `@Assert` annotations for both entities in their respective files. While `company` validation works, `location` does not get automatically validated.

I managed to get validation by adding `constraint` properties to the new `$builder->create('location')` elements, but this means duplicated code (once in Entity and at least once in every form that needs `location`).

How can I solve it so the form gets validated by using the entity's annotation?

Comment: isn't better to create custom validator (to handle case a location already exists or company cant be in the location ...)? if so see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

Comment: @εEridani Good idea (I'm quite new to symfony ..). Now the error pops up above the form and is not mapped to a field. I tried [`error_mapping`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-mapping) but can't seem to get it to work (Used `.` on the left side, still appears above form)

Comment: Use "Class constraints" then in the Context do something like:
 public function validate($myLocationEntity, Constraint $constraint) {
    context->addViolationAt ( 'FIELD_NAME', "duplication area or some   randome message", array (), null );
   }

then in the twig you must add:
 {{ form_errors(form.FIELD_TO_VALIDATE) }}

Comment: @εEridani Will keep this in mind, for now `@Assert\Valid` does a fine job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default validation won't traverse to properties that are objects or collections. Use the [valid constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html

You cans set the traverse option for collections as well.